# Use context in React with Typescript and Auth0

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-context

I want to make a context file in which I put a Auth0 identification that is passed as props. Unfortunately I just started with typescript and thus I'm quite struggeling. Here is my file.

```
import React from 'react';
import { createContext, useContext} from 'react'
import { Auth0Provider } from '@auth0/auth0-react'


export const Auth0Context = createContext(<Partial<ContextProps>>({}));


const domain = process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_DOMAIN;
const clientId = process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_CLIENT_ID;



const authValues: any  = {
  domain: React.ReactChild, 
  clientId: React.ReactChild
}


export default function AuthProvider({children:React.ReactNode}){


  return (
    <Auth0Context.Provider>
      <Auth0Provider
          value={authValues}
      >
        {children}
      </Auth0Provider>
    </Auth0Context.Provider>
  );
}
```

For instance, I'm not sure of which type the env variables are and how I can declare the children type accurately. Thanks very much for helping me out!